# Regular Expression Constraints route

Tags: php, laravel

I want something like the bottom line:

```
Route::get('/{service}', 'SeminarController@index')->where('service','!=',user');
```

I have a root like the one below:

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
```

Comment: Route where works with regular expression. So just make correct regular expression.
This will maybe help, how to make expression as 'not match' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word

Answer (score 0):

Put your route:

`Route::get('/{service}', 'SeminarController@index')`

under

`Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');`

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('/{service}', 'SeminarController@index');
```

that's all